# Null route value passes in ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to Asp.net MVC. I want to create the hyper Links of some object of Model in this way

```
  <ul>@foreach(Department department in @Model ) 
    {         
      <li>@Html.ActionLink(department.Name, "Index", "Employee", new {departmentid= department.Id },null)</li>   
    } </ul>
```

Now as it shows, when I click on Link in browser, it should move to Index action of employee controller with department.Id route value.But when I click the link, it passes a null route value, but in URL , it shows the correct value. Why is that like this? Any help?

this is the Index Action in Employee controller

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

             employees.AddRange(db.Employees.ToList().Where(x => x.DepartmentId == id));

            return View(employees);
        }
```

Comment: What does your action look like? It's likely the names of the parameters don't match

Comment: Which parameter names? would you explain a bit? @Liam

Comment: change ``new {departmentid= department.Id }`` to ``new {id= department.Id }``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implmenting your action call wrong. the names in the anonymous object (`new {departmentid= department.Id }`) and the parameter names must match. Change `departmentid` to `id` (because your action expects a parameter called id `Index(int id)`):

```
@Html.ActionLink(department.Name, "Index", "Employee", new {id= department.Id },null)
```

Comment: Ohhh... I thought that was just an alias sort of thing... Thanks very much. It works :)

Comment: It uses [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx) to match them so the names must match